# Is Ask Metafilter better than SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, asking-questions

Do you have any experience with programming related questions in [Ask Metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/)?

- Do you get more experts there and are your answers better?
- Do they reply quickly and does every question get answered, considering its a paid service?

The typical Ask Metafilter questions that I find using Google have excellent answers...

Comment: The typical Stack Overflow questions that I find using Google have excellent answers, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a fairly radically different (and much wider) audience, so a bit of apples to oranges.

I am a big fan of Metafilter as covered on previous podcasts, though!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/podcast-22/

Not to knock MeFi at all, but SO, being a dedicated programming community, should do far better on prgramming questions -- and I'd be seriously concerned if it didn't.